# Ruby: strings concated with "\n" returned in one line

Tags: ruby, merge, newline, concatenation

I have this code:

```
def rectangle
  "|------------------|\n" +
  "|                  |\n" +
  "|                  |\n" +
  "|                  |\n" +
  "|                  |\n" +
  "|                  |\n" +
  "|                  |\n" +
  "|                  |\n" +
  "|                  |\n" +
  "|------------------|\n"
  end
```

and I want to refactor it. But for some reason, if I try to concat/merge the strings in any other way `"\n"` stops working, and it's returned in one line.

```
def rectangle
    a = "|------------------|\n"
    b = "|                  |\n"
    a + b + a
end
```

I tried using

```
System.getProperty("line.separator", "\n")
```

as suggested in similar posts, but it's not helpful (or I'm not doing it right). It's part of my course. Feels like I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: A string is always one line when displayed via `inspect`. It's only multiple lines if you print it. Did you try that? Don't forget Ruby can multiply strings: `'-' * 10` is a lot easier to work with than what you have here.

Comment: if I use print then it will return nil, I want it to return a square that's made of - and | as silly as it sounds

Comment: `puts` and friends return `nil`, that's what they do. Display the string and it will look fine. I think you're confusing the `inspect` notation with the actual content.

Comment: They gave us a test, and I thought it's not working but it is. Ha! Well, thank you for your patience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple example is:

```
def rectangle
  a = "|#{'-' * 10}|"
  b = "|#{' ' * 10}|"
  ([a] + [b] * 5 + [a]).join("\n")
end

puts rectangle
```

Comment: Even better: `[a] + [b] * rows + [a]`.